# Meaning of << operator in C

Tags: c, operators

I am wondering to know What is the meaning of operator `<<` in

```
#define  x (10 * (1<<12));
```

Comment: It's a left bit shift?

Comment: It's a left shift operator, as any [decent book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would tell you.

Comment: Not two `<<` is single operator, bitwise left shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [bitshift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). `<<` is **shift left**,  `>>` is **shift right**. `1 << 12` means shift the value (the int '1') 12 bits to the left.

'1' is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001` in binary, if it's a 32 bit integer.
To shift it left 12 places, changes it to: `00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000`

If you were to shift `5 << 8`, '5' is `101` in binary, so it'll shift:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
```

Into:

```
00000000 00000000 00000101 00000000
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) for details on the other bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1):

It means 1 shifted 12 bits to the left.  You can find thisand more at a quick reference at:

http://www.sourcepole.ch/sources/programming/cpp/cppqref.html